# How to load text letter by letter on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello everyone I'm trying to load my h2 text once when I scroll to div and the content of h2 have to load letter by letter like typewriter. I have try in this way but it doesnt work. Have you guys any idea?

```
$(window).scroll( function(){   
        $('.inner h2').each(function (i){          
            var header = $(this);
            var header_content = header.html();
            var content = new Array();
            content[i] = header_content;
            position = new Array();
            position[i] = $(this).position().top;
            console.log(content[i]+' pos '+position);     

            var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

            if( bottom_of_window > position[i] ){
                var arrayTitle = content[i].split('');
                var i = 0;              

                var interval = setInterval(function(){
                if (i > arrayTitle.length) 
                {
                  header.html(content[i]);        // wipe out the <span> tags
                  clearInterval(interval);
                } 
                else
                {
                  $('<span>')
                    .html(arrayTitle[i])
                    .appendTo(header)
                    .hide()
                    .fadeIn(50);                    
                    i++;      
                }
                }, 50);

            }            
        }); 

    });
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2017/)

Comment: you have two vars i, change one and delete the header.html outside the setInterval [http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2018/](http://jsfiddle.net/e5qaD/2018/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my take: http://jsfiddle.net/Sladkoff/73TDB/

I put the scroll event handler inside the each function. 
This way, each element has its own 'instance' variables and handler.
It requires some more tweaking, but maybe this will help you as a base.

This makes little sense to me:

I did not append the span, as I didn't really understand from your description/code what exactly you're trying to achieve with it.

If this is not what you wanted, then at least I cleaned up a little :)

```
// I would have just left a comment if I could.
```